# Call C# method from JavaScript with parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, methods

I want to call a C# method with parameter from JavaScript. It is possible, if I remove the parameter `s` of the method `<% showDetail(); %>`

```
function showDetail(kurz)
        {
            String s = kurz.toString();
            <% showDetail(s); %>;
        }
```

**C# methods to test:**

```
public void showDetail(String s)
        {
            Label_Test.Text = s.ToString();
        }
public void showDetail()
        {
            Label_Test.Text = "";
        }
```

It works fine without parameter but with `s` variable I  get a compiler error:

> CS0103: The name 's' does not exist in the current context

I have tried

```
showDetail(Object s){....}
```

and also

```
showDetail(String s){....}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm

Comment: are you using a c# windows application?

Comment: Can you specify if you're using ASP.NET and whether it is WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Thank you guys I will try it and @sumeshk yes I'm usind c# windows application

Comment: I don't think your are writting a Windows Application with such tags `<%` `%>`

Comment: Oh...i am surprised and worried too.. does C# Windows application supports Javascript. which version of VISUAL STUDIO you are using ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a web method. That's an easy and neat way of calling c# methods from Javascript. You can call that method using jQuery Ajax. See the below example for a webMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string RegisterUser(string s)
{
    //do your stuff
    return stringResult;
}
```

and then call this method using jQuery ajax. You can pass parameters also. like given below

```
function showDetail(kurz) { 
String sParam = kurz.toString(); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName", 
    data: "{s:sParam}", // passing the parameter 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(retValue) {
        // Do something with the return value from.Net method
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I've tryed but it does not work, cound you please give me an full solution or tutorial?

Comment: @SigiAnonym I have editted my answer and added the jScript method. Please try this one

Comment: Would I be able to host it in IIS and call it from a browser? How do I create the WebMethod? What type of project is it? I would like to know how the whole process works from creating to testing, any docs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hidden field to pass the value(set the value using javascript.). And call the javscript function with out parameter.. That value u can get it from the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve this by using WebMethods

First of all create a webmethod.

```
    [WebMethod]
public string MethodName(string Parameter)
{
string msg=string.Empty;
//Your Code
return msg;
}
```

And in Java Script call that functions as

```
WebService.MethodName(Parameter,onSuccess,Error) // Here Webservice is the name of your asmx file

function onSuccess(result)
{
//Your code
}

function Error()
{
alert("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution provide by Varun Paul is the one I have used and it works as long you correct the following error: data: "{s:sParam}",

It should be written as:
data: {
       s:sParam
},

data is used to pass parameters to the C# method.
Hope it helps.
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to interact `c# application` with `javascrip`t, use `jint.dll` for that

[Jint - Javascript Interpreter for .NET](http://jint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start)

For Example

Following are the java script functions

```
function reverse(my_str)  
{ 
    var sb = new jintTestApplication.Test();//jintTestApplication is the namespace name
    return sb.Test1(reverse2(my_str) );
} 

function reverse2(my_str)  
{    
 var comStr="";  
    var result="";  
    var i=my_str.length;  

    i=i-1;  
     for (var x = i; x >=0; x--)  
      {  
        result= my_str.charAt(x);  
        comStr+=result;  
       }  
   return comStr; 
}
```

so in this case *you have to create the object of your class inside the javascript and is possible to call a c#  method*

```
            JintEngine engine = new JintEngine();
            engine.Run(ReadJavaScript());
            Console.WriteLine(engine.Run("reverse('Foooooo');"));

   public static  string ReadJavaScript()
   {
    string allines = File.ReadAllText(@"[path]\test.js");
   }



public void Test1(string message)
{
MessageBox.show(message);
}
```

Comment: This is for running JavaScript on the server. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: No, we can communicate our c# application with a javascript function using this dll,i used this in my application and able to communicate with the javascript, calls a javascript function from c#  methods and vice versa

Comment: Even tough the question isn't exactly explicit about that, I am pretty sure the OP needs to do that over HTTP in an ASP.NET application. Jint won't help with that.

Comment: @xavier-poinas From comment i think he is using a c# windows application, and down voting i think is unnecessary "Thank you guys I will try it and sumeshk yes I'm usind c# windows application"