# How can I call a Code Behind method with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to call a Code Behind method with JS. I already tried `[WebMethod]`. I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610042/call-c-sharp-method-from-javascript-with-parameter). But my code behind is not getting called. I pasted code below so you can find out actual problem for that.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sendMail()
{
var arr = [];
arr.push('foo');
arr.push('bar');
arr.push('bazz');

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "~/Modules/Masters/Email.aspx/SendMail",
                data: "{info:arr}", // passing the parameter 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (retValue) {
                    // Do something with the return value from.Net method
                }
            });
}
</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendMail(string[] info)
{
    return "";
}
```

Does it need any library. I already have
 `<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my `.Master` file.

Comment: Do you get an error in Firebug? maybe in the Net tab?

Comment: @markpsmith No error.

Comment: I am assuming when you say Code Behind, this is a generic handler (.ashx?) and not the page code behind file? As you are trying to do a post using AJAX?

Comment: No, because the link I followed has aspx and not ashx, should I use ashx?

Comment: Your main issue has been spotted by Issac in his answer. You cannot use `~` in javascript, as that is used by ASP.NET to denote the root of the application

Answer (score 1):

try removing the "~" from the url in your ajax call. I don't think javascript can handle it well.

Comment: You are correct... `~` is used by ASP.NET as a shortcut for the root of the application, it is not something that can be used with javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things that can be wrong, firstly you will need a ScriptManager on your page too!

Comment: Yes, I have. Should I set some attribute for that?

Comment: Yes <asp:scriptmanager enablepagemethods="true" id="scpt" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager> 

I've used this approach before, its slightly different but has the same effect -> http://www.techillumination.in/2013/07/an-aspnet-way-to-call-server-side.html maybe see what the differnces between it and your solution is

Answer (score 0):

i am sending mail from pure html page using wcf service may be useful to you please chk this code:

html page:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reqinfo').click(function () {
           // debugger;
            var emailto = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
            if (emailto != "") {


                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/EmailService1.svc/EmailService1/emaildata?Email=" + emailto,
                    // data: dat,
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                    //    debugger;


                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                       // debugger;

                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                //your validation message goes here
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Wcf service: IEmailService page

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/EmailService1/emaildata?Email={Email}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string emaildata(string Email);
```

wcf service code page:

```
public string emaildata(string Email)
    {
      //your email code.....
    }
```

Web.config code:

```
    <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
   <files>
    <add value="Service1.svc" />

   </files>
   </defaultDocument>

  <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
   <add name="ISAPI64" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
</handlers>
 </system.webServer>

 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service name="SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService1" name="samendpoint" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehaviour">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"   />

    </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>

    <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>

    </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>

     </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
       <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"
      automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
      </standardEndpoints>
     </system.serviceModel>
```

and do't forget to add Factory setting in  markup of wcf service by right click on wcf service in solution explorer and go to view mark up

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```

like in my code i set for example:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="PSICMS.EmailService1" CodeBehind="EmailService1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendMail(string info)
{
    return "";
}
```

Here info has comma separated values, you can split them and use.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine as far as calling the method. I'm assuming that your path to the method is incorrect. When I use this approach, the `[WebMethod]` would live in the code-behind of the same page, so I would use `url: "Email.aspx/SendEmail` I would also add an error handler to your `$.ajax` call to help with debugging. add this after your success handler. `error: function(a,b,c){alert(a.responseText);}` this should tell you what the problem is. You also don't need a script manager to make any of this work.