# Calling a C# method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, code-behind

I want to to call a method `GetAccount` from my controller `AccountController.cs`, in my JavaScript factory `LoginFactory.js`. Something like this:

**AccountController.cs:**

```
public Account GetAccount(string userName)
    { ... }
```

**LoginFactory.js:**

```
if(x>y) {
   var account = <%AccountController.GetAccount(someParam);%>
}
```

I've tried using `[WebMethod]` and Ajax, but I can't get it to work: I get a 404 response.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your Ajax request? And did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610042/call-c-sharp-method-from-javascript-with-parameter) post?

Comment: You cannot call a method directly from client side to server side. Instead, use a service or `WebMethod`. You are claiming that this doesn't work, so please post the code that is failing, both javascript and C# otherwise it will be hard to determine whats wrong.

Comment: If you're getting a 404, almost certainly, your webservice is not deployed onto the server you're hitting or you're hitting the wrong server. I'd look at a Fiddler/Firebug trace to see that it's going to the correct path for your IIS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** your `GetAccount` method can be reached at `/Account/GetAccount` when your application runs, you could use the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Account/GetAccount',
  data: { 'username' : 'a-username' },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(jsonData) {
    alert(jsonData);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

Note - this is dependant on jQuery.

This causes the **browser** to make a request to `/Account/GetAccount` as if you  had done so by entering the URL in the URL bar, but of course, captures the returned json for use in your client side (javascript) script.

If this returns a 404, it would be worth checking your routing.