# Call C# server side from Javascript with parameter passing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I know this question has been asked before but nothing so far has helped me reach a final solution.

I have an ASP web page that has numerous buttons that perform different functions. I also have a dropdown box that contains a list of objects. When I select an item from the dropdown, the button functionality remains the same in each button, however I would like a function called on the server in my C# code that receives a couple of key variables that I can then pass to an API. If only one parameter can be passed, I could pass it as a JSON string, so this is not a restriction any possible solutions should be concerned with.

What I am having trouble with is determining the best way to do this. I have read some possibilities in things like using AJAX calls, an OnCommand attribute inside the asp button, WebMethods and a few other more obscure possibilities. I would like to avoid the hidden field approach as it does seem pretty hacky. That being said, I am open to changing my thoughts if people really do think it is the best way.

The relevant parts of my code are as follows:

**Javascript code**

```
function testAJAX()
{
    //The console.log was called successfully, however the ProcessData function was never hit correctly
    /*console.log("hello");     
    PageMethods.ProcessData("Hello", successAjax, failAjax);*/

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "UserManagement.aspx/ProcessData", 
        data: '{data:"Hello"}', // passing the parameter 
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(retValue) {
            // Do something with the return value from.Net method
            alert(retValue);
            } 
        }); 
}

function successAjax(response) {
    alert(response.get_message());
}

function failAjax(response) {
    alert(response.get_message());
}
```

**C# code (debugging was attempted on data += " from the server";)**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string ProcessData(string data)
{
    data += " from the server";
    return data;
}
```

**Calling the Javascript code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server" />
    <button onclick="testAJAX()">Test AJAX</button>
</form>
```

For the life of me, I simply can not get ANY Ajax or Web Method calls hitting my breakpoint in the server side code. I have tried:

- Copying the AJAX from the top answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610042/call-c-sharp-method-from-javascript-with-parameter) and changing the variables so that it points to my function (url: "UserManagement.aspx/ProcessData",)
- Moving my script tag to be inside the body tag
- Adding a ScriptManager to my form
- Made sure I was not using a Master page as apparently that changes things
- Using PageMethods.ProcessData(). This seems to be the closest, as it actually did hit the success function, but didn't seem to hit my ProcessData function...

I'm really at a loss as to why it is not debugging on the server, if anyone has any suggestions, that would be fantastic. I'm assuming I am missing something small, but it certainly seems to be enough to halt progress. Once I can debug, I should be good to go. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please add your code as text rather than an image

Comment: sure thing, will edit that now

Comment: Have you tried to test your server endpoint going to "UserManagment.aspx/ProcessData" directly on your web browser? Also, you are sending a plain string in the ajax data, not a json. And you are defining the ajax response as json (but the server is adding a plain string to the response, I think this will give an error too).

Comment: @IonGorostizuAlbeniz I haven't tried that, I wasn't aware that you could but it makes sense now that you mention it. I will try it out and report back. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Ok, so it seems that when the answer comes back from ProcessData, I am just getting the full HTML page back. I tried this from PostMan.

Comment: I think in the ajax request the type must be GET instead of POST.

Comment: @Gaurav You are definitely onto something there. Changing it made it so that the alert appeared, but I still didn't hit the function. I'm going to try changing the name of the function in case it is clashing with something else or something weird like that. EDIT: Changing the name did not help. Ah well

Comment: Ok then make two more changes here :
 change  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" and add another property for dataType: "json"

Comment: @Gaurav I had changed it to what it is in the question now (dataType: "text" and contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", but to no avail. Sorry that I didn't mention that in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing your data correctly

```
// data:"{data:Hello}", its not correct
```

remove and do that like this

```
data: { data: Hello },
```

and you can pass Hello variable like this

```
var Hello = "test";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'UserManagement.aspx/ProcessData',
            data: { data: Hello },               
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, I've fixed that up (silly mistake on my part), but I am still not hitting the function on the server. I will edit that part of the code in my question to prevent any confusion.

Comment: the `data` prop does not have to be a string, you can just get rid of all that nasty concatenation and do this : 
`$.ajax({type: 'post', url:'something', data : {data:Hello}});`